# How to display a TableView and another view through one ViewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I'm learning how to develop in Swift currently. I'd like to be able to replicate the functionality displayed in the Apple Music UI screenshot below.

At a high level, I'd like a table view to select songs from a list while being able to control the AV settings on the same screen.

What would be the best (simple and configurable) methods of approaching this?

Currently I have the functionality of both a media player and the table view with scrolling in separate view controllers. I've looked into implementing a split view or trying to use a stack view but have been running into roadblocks.

Comment: There's no screenshot in your question.

Comment: What roadblocks have you been running into? Update your question with specific details about what you have tried and what issues you are having.

Answer (score 1):

A view controller can easily display both a table view and other content.

You'd just create a custom subclass of UIViewController, and have that custom view controller class conform to both the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. You'd then implement the methods you need from those protocols to support your table view. Then when you set up your view controllers (in code or in your storyboard) you'd connect your table view's delegate and data source outlets to your view controller.

Also note that it's quite easy to put a (child) view controller's content view inside another (parent) view controller. Open the parent view controller in Interface Builder, tap on the "+" in the window's title bar to show the component library, and search on "Container View". Drag a container view into your parent view controller's view and set up the constraints you want to position the view. Then right-drag/control drag from your container view to the child view controller you want to embed in the parent, and select "embed". This creates an "embed segue" that does all the work to instantiate your child view controller and host it's view inside the parent view controller.